# Assembly Printf Segfault With ASCII

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault

For an assembly program I'm writing I want to print an ascii character that is stored in %dil. (The rest of %rdi is empty and %al contains the ascii code) I wrote the following code:

```
mov $0, %rdi
mov %al, %dil
mov $0, %rax
call printf
```

How come this gives a segmentation fault? And what can I do to fix this?

Comment: `printf` takes a string as its argument, not a character.  So it expects a pointer to a null-terminated string in `rdi`.  To print just one character, you could use `putchar` instead.

Comment: Apart from the other suggestion you can `printf` the string `"%c",0` and then pass that string's address as the first parameter and the character code as a subsequent parameter.

Comment: `movzbl %al, %edi` is the standard efficient way to zero-extend a byte into a 64-bit register.  So you could `movzbl %al, %esi` and then `lea format_char(%rip), %rdi` if you had a `format_char: .asciz "%c"` somewhere.  Exactly the same as in C, you can't `printf(c)`.